# '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str' while jsonify dict

Tags: python, json, flask, jsonify

I am getting below error while jsonify.

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'numpy.ndarray' and 'str'
```

My code is:

```
if rows[0]:
        print("row1",rows[1])
        #data_json = str(rows[1])
        data_json = jsonify(rows[1])
```

Expecting Json object but getting error.

Answer (score 0):

`jsonify` only accepts dictionaries, lists, and primitive data types as input. Convert the `numpy.ndarray` to a list and then pass it to `jsonify`.

```
if rows[0]:
        print("row1",rows[1])
        data_json = jsonify(rows[1].tolist())
```